# Block user login from Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal4j

Is it possible to block login through Azure portal for a user but at the same time allow the user to get authenticated through API (ADAL4J API)?

I have an application where I use admin credentials for operations on users. However I want to restrict login through Azure Portal for this user. If I set up MFA for the user will the authentication through API stop working too?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your scenario - application creds and authz are separate from Azure authz...  You can't block access to the portal but you don't have to give the user access to anything in the subscription either (so they can log in, but are not authorized to do anything)...

Comment: I've never tried this, but AAD may allow you to block a specific app. I kind of doubt this is possible, but might be worth looking into. You can get the portal's app id by base64 decoding one the authorization header used to talk to management.azure.com.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, you cannot specifically block access to portal (and that makes no sense whatsoever)
2. Yes, MFA will affect you user logins, you won't be able to login without MFA

Comment: To add, you can associate certain resources or apps with conditional access policies to only require MFA for certain objects.